# Table wasn't created when making custom user model

Tags: django

The table wasn't created when I made custom user model.

In my settings.py, I installed my app and defined AUTH_USER_MODEL

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'rest_framework',

#My apps
'accounts',
]
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'
```

my model is below (at accounts app)

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
key = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
email= models.EmailField('email',unique=True)
name=models.CharField('name',max_length=20) #model.USERNAME_FIELD
is_active=models.BooleanField('is_active',default=True)
is_admin=models.BooleanField('is_admin',default=False)
date_joined = models.DateTimeField('date_joined',default=timezone.now)

objects = UserManager()
USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
#EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'

class Meta:
    swappable = "AUTH_USER_MODEL"
```

I executed makemigrations && migrate.
And I've also tried makemigrations accounts && migrate accounts

but still there is no accounts_user table.

Answer (score 0):

Step-1 delete migration folder

Step-2 run command (python manage.py makemigrations your app name

Step -3 run command (python manage.py migrate)

If still not working...??

repate above steps
but this time also deleted sqlite3 database

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Database deleting was worked for me!